# How to expose several ports for docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

How to expose multiple ports in docker-compose.yml for one container? For example, I need to expose port for postgresql container and if 5432 is occupied (by local postgresql) than set it to the next one in range 5432-5442. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your compose you can expose ports using range.

```
   ports:
     - "5432-5442:5432"
```

Or according docker compose docs

```
   ports:
     - "5432"
```

This will pick up a random port on the host machine and map it to 5432.

Comment: He is not asking how to forward multiple ports, but how to pick an available local port to pass on to the fixed port inside a container.  For example if he already has one host running with a mapping of 80:80, he wants the next host to use 81:80 -- though with different (pgsql) ports.

Comment: I didn't notice his question was asking specifically about compose so I deleted my answer.  Don't you actually want `5432-5442:5432` here though?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but I talked about the opposite thing. "5432:5432-5442". By this I mean that specific port on the host machine should be mapped to the one non-occupied in range. Is such thing possible?